# PyDrake: PID Control of Free-Floating Simulation - Velocity & Positional Dimension Mismatch

Tags: drake

|OS: Ubuntu 20.04|Py:3.7|Drake Stable Release:0.38.0|
When I generate a free-floating body (conventional robotic arm not welded to world with n joints) I get the following:

Positional DOF: [[quaternion],x,y,z,j1,j2...], DOF # = n + 7
Velocity DOF: [roll,pitch,yaw,x,y,z,j1,j2...], DOF # = n + 6

This matrix mismatch prevents me from implementing PID control because the PidController class wants Kp,Ki, and Kd to be the same length, and it must be applied to the whole state context, even though for the sake of control the only nonzero gains would be for the joint values ji for i = 1-n.

Am I missing something?

Thanks --

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PidController](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1controllers_1_1_pid_controller.html) system accepts `state_projection` and `output_projection` matrices precisely to support this sort of a workflow.

Comment: Follow-up:
(1) The function that takes a state_projection matrix mandates that the rows of P_x be 2* |q_d|, indicating that I'm mandated to have a PID input port connection size of 2*|q_d|. Is the only purpose of that overloading to enable floating systems? 
(2) I'd like to pass a joint trajectory to the "desired position" input. Desired velocity is going to be varied between simulation tests. How do I generate a single output port that contains both a position trajectory and a velocity trajectory, if piecewisepoly & traj block have no append function? (multiplexer appears inappropriate)

Comment: (1) Floating systems are a common example, but this supports running PID control on any system that doesn't have actuators on all of the joints.
(2) Multiplexer seems perfectly appropriate to me!  But you could also build the appended piecewisepolynomial yourself (e.g. using this constructor: https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1trajectories_1_1_piecewise_polynomial.html#a9145f61319cb888cb71fc58cebc8fe38).  I agree it would be nice to have an append method that makes it easier.